# Selenium-Python Instagram Followers Scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

Having an issue getting the whole list of followers for an Instagram account using Selenium in Python. My code seems to be scrolling down the followers popup window and loading the followers but it always comes short of the total number of followers that instagram says someone has. For example, it says X user has 438 followers and after one run it stops at 407 and another run stops at 416...etc...Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Summary:
Tried using the scoll_script in python to scroll the followers popup: "arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;"
Then iterate through the follower elements using an incremental index breaking the while loop when the index reaches the end of all loaded follower elements.

Expecting: The number of followers names collected to match what instagram reports on a users profile but this is not the case. Scrolling in the followers popup window not loading all followers.

```
from AUTH_APP import instagram_2FA_code
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import CREDENTIALS
import os
import pyotp
import random



user = ''
parent_dir = "C:/PYTHON_PROJECTS/SELENIUM/"

# MAKE_follower_usernames_dir
try:
    os.makedirs(parent_dir + user + "/FOLLOWERS/")
except:
    pass

followers_dir = f"C:/PYTHON_PROJECTS/SELENIUM/{user}/FOLLOWERS/"
followers_usernames_txt_name = f"{user}_followers_usernames.txt"
followers_names_txt_name = f"{user}_followers_names.txt"

# OPEN
followers_username_txt = open(rf"{followers_dir}{followers_usernames_txt_name}", "w", encoding="utf-8")
followers_name_txt = open(rf"{followers_dir}{followers_names_txt_name}", "w", encoding="utf-8")

load_dotenv()
totp = pyotp.TOTP(instagram_2FA_code)

USERNAME = CREDENTIALS.USERNAME
PASSWORD = CREDENTIALS.PASSWORD

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

insta_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'


def get_random_int_dec(integer):
    random_delay = integer + random.random()
    return random_delay

# OPEN INSTAGRAM LOGIN PAGE
driver.get(insta_URL)
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# ACCEPT COOKIES
accept_cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]')))
accept_cookies.click()
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# FILL IN USERNAME
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
username_field.send_keys(USERNAME)
sleep(get_random_int_dec(2))

# FILL IN PASSWORD
password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
password_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# CLICK LOGIN
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button/div')))
login_button.click()
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# 2FA
two_factor_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'verificationCode')))
insta_2fa = totp.now()
two_factor_field.send_keys(insta_2fa)
sleep(get_random_int_dec(3))


# 2FA CLICK BUTTON
two_FA_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/button')))
two_FA_button.click()

sleep(get_random_int_dec(5))

# CLICK DONT REMEMBER LOGIN
not_now_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/div/div/div/div/div')))
not_now_button.click()
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# GET SOMEONES FOLLOWERS
driver.get(insta_URL + f'{user}/followers')
sleep(get_random_int_dec(5))


# GET NUMBER OF FOLLOWERS
follower_count_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'ul')))
list_items = follower_count_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

followers_list_item = list_items[1].text
followers_list_item_split = followers_list_item.split(' ')
follower_count = followers_list_item_split[0]


print(f"{user} # of followers: {follower_count}")
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))



# Wait for the followers popup to load
followers_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]')))
sleep(get_random_int_dec(1))

# Scroll down the followers popup
scroll_script = "arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;"

username_list = []
name_list = []

i = 1


# LOAD ALL FOLLOWERS FIRST
load_counter = 50
while load_counter > 0:
    driver.execute_script(scroll_script, followers_popup)
    sleep(5)
    load_counter = load_counter - 1
    print(f"Load counter: {load_counter}")

# GET ALL LOADED FOLLOWERS
element_found_counter = 0
while True:
    username_found = False
    name_found = False

    try:
        # LOOK FOR MAIN ELEMENT
        MAIN_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{i}]")
        try:
            # LOOK FOR USERNAME ELEMENT
            follower_username_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div")
            follower_username_text = follower_username_element.text
            username_list.append(follower_username_text)


            username_found = True
        except:
            pass
        try:
            # LOOK FOR NAME ELEMENT
            follower_name_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span")
            follower_name_text = follower_name_element.text
            name_list.append(follower_name_text)

            name_found = True
        except:
            pass


    except:
        print(f"Could not find element: {i}")
        break


    if (username_found or name_found) == True:
        element_found_counter = element_found_counter + 1
        print(element_found_counter)


    # INCREMENT INDEX
    i = i + 1







# name_list_len = len(name_list)

# WRITE FOLLOWERS TO DISK
print("---USERNAMES:")
for un in username_list:
    un_string = un.encode('utf-8')
    followers_username_txt.write(un)
    followers_username_txt.write("\n")
    print(un)

# print("---NAMES:")
# for n in name_list:
#     n_string = un.encode('utf-8')
#     followers_username_txt.write(n)
#     followers_username_txt.write("\n")
#     print(n)


# print(f"Number of usernames: {username_list_len}")
# print(f"Number of names: {name_list_len}")



# CLOSE DRIVER
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.